# Storing values from array of interface objects to an array of strings

Tags: typescript, tsx

In this code:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {useFetchErrors} from "../Api/Api";
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
interface ExecutionTableProps {
  project_id: number
}

const ErrorsPage: React.FC<ExecutionTableProps> = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    // @ts-ignore
    const errors = useFetchErrors(location.state.project_id)
    let array = []
    for (const element in errors) {
        array.push(element)
    }
    return(
       <React.Fragment> {array}</React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default ErrorsPage;
```

I'm trying to store the string elements from an array of interface objects to "array", ie this part of the code:

```
 let array = []
    for (const element in errors) {
        array.push(element)
    }
    return(
       <React.Fragment> {array}</React.Fragment>
    )
```

Errors (the array of interface objects) contains interface objects that look like this:

```
export interface IError{
    id:number,
    error:string,
    scan_id:number
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the error value from each IError object in the errors array and store them in array. How can I change what I currently have to accomplish this in TSX?

Comment: I assume you're just going to use `errors.map(x => x.error)`, but I can't test this because I don't have a [mre]. Please consider posting a code example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N7Oj4N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, but I don't even know enough typescript to make MRE. I'm trying to fix someone else's codebase.

Comment: To clarify, my *guess* here is that you should just write `let array = errors.map(x => x.error)` and forget about your `for` loop.  If the above code works for you I can maybe write up an answer, but I don't want to spend effort explaining something that doesn't actually solve the problem, so please check.   If it doesn't work for you and you can't figure out how to ask the question in a way that other people can test then I don't know what kind of help you can get here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should help you.

```
interface ArrayOfErrors {
    id:number,
    error:string,
    scan_id:number
};

const array :ArrayOfErrors[] = [];
```